# Bash script: Use of date in foldername for calculation (Delete folders older than X)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find, directory

We have backup foldernames like "*db*_YYYY-MM-DD".

**Is there some kind of command/expression I could use to compare the folder's (name-)date to the current (system-)date and delete anything older than X days?**

Background:
We already tried "find" and "-mtime +X" but modification time is not a perfect solution *because it updates when you modify/delete files inside the folders afterwards*..

It is a rare condition but makes the -mtime comparison "faulty", so I look for an alternative and *the folder's name doesn't change ever during creation/backup/modification*..

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way to generate the folder name

```
#foldername="db_"`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
#echo $foldername
db_2017-08-15
#mkdir $foldername
```

Now you can compare like string with given date

so 7 days older date will be

```
 givenDate="db_"`date -v-7d "+%Y-%m-%d"`
```

if ($foldername > $givenDate)

```
 True if foldername sorts after givenDate lexicographically.
```

Comment: But if month is different?

Comment: It also does the trick for month and year. Year is compared first, then month and then day

Comment: Also I have provided a way to calculate the date x days back. Do check

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about the `YYYY-MM-DD` date format is that the dictionary comparison order matches the time order. Therefore you can simply extract the backup date from your directory name and compare it as a string with the corresponding date in the same format:

```
backupdirname=db_2017-08-12
X=6

backupdate="${backupdirname: -10}"
dropdate="$(date -d "$X days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)"

if [[ "$backupdate" < "$dropdate" ]]
then
    echo "Delete $backupdirname"
else
    echo "Keep $backupdirname"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ref_date=$(date -d '2017-01-02' +%s)
for file in ./db_*; do
    file_time=$(date -d ${file#*db_} +%s)
    if [[ $file_time > $ref_date ]]; then
        echo "$file date is newer than ref date"
        # ...
    else
        echo "$file date is older or euqal to ref date"
        # ...
    fi  
done
```